# Set WPF UserControl properties to a Control inside it

Tags: c#, wpf

So, for example, I made a UserControl to improve default WPF ProgressBar, sth like ProgressBarPlus or whatever, so I need to have all property values of the UserControl set to a ProgressBar inside it, there should be some way other than adding each property of ProgressBar (Value, Maximum, SmallChange, LargeChange etc...) to my UserControl manually, then set my ProgressBar properties according to my UserControl properties.

To sum it up, I need to make my UserControl act exactly as a ProgressBar (its properties and events) but with a few controls added to it to make its functionality better.

Couldn't find anything on google, any ideas?

Comment: See marked duplicate for the basic approach: create a dependency property for each property you want to map to the `ProgressBar`, then use `{TemplateBinding...}` in the XAML to map those dependency properties to the `ProgressBar` properties.

Comment: So,no way to map the whole ProgressBar to the UserControl directy?

Comment: No, not really. There's not any out-of-the-box solution that automatically maps properties from a control to a `UserControl` that contains it. The `UserControl` properties have to be declared in code, and you have to bind to them in your XAML.

Comment: Aha OK. thanks for your answer (: